# How to achieve this responsive layout with flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, sass, flexbox, responsive-design

I'm making a React app which renders xy number of cards and a single widget inside a flex container. All cards have the same width and height, but widget's height equals to `card height * 2 + row-gap`. The container's width varries based on viewport width and should visually look as 2 or 3 columns with cards respectively. I'm providing a mockup image of needed layouts for further clarity, widget is depicted with blue color.

[image: Layout mockup]

Whatever I tried, I couldn't get the widget to display in the correct spot without changing the height of the row to its size, leaving a "blank row" where 1 or 2 more cards should be rendered as displayed on the following image.

[image]

My current solution involves Javascript, where based on the viewport width I'm loading 2 or 4 cards into a separate small flex container which is rendered as the first child of the main flex container. This workaround works great visually, but complicates my code a lot seeing as i have to cover many different cases for it to function correctly. I want to achieve the same thing using css/flexbox but I'm still a beginner, have never done a layout like this before and obviously can't figure out how to do so. Widget **can't** be `absolutely positioned` because that breaks the scroll functionality of its child element.

I'm providing test HTML and CSS measurements in correct ratio in case it helps.

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  row-gap: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
  min-width: 320px; /* Width for 2 columns */
  max-width: 490px; /* Width for 3 columns */
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 22, 117);
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.widget {
  height: 220px; /* card height * 2 + row-gap */
  width: 150px;
  background-color: rgb(134, 204, 245);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="widget"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>

<!-- Original jsx
<div className='container'>
  <div className='widget'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
</div>
-->
```

I really want to learn how to create layouts such as this one in flexbox, not only because of my current project, but also to expand my knowledge and understanding in general. Please help me if you have any idea on how to solve this. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You definitely want to use Grid for this, not Flexbox.

Comment: @Paulie_D Hello, not sure the duplicate is pertinent, the main rule to mind about here is grid-column-end ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Flexbox layout is unable to do this**, it does not create a 2d grid, you will have to use the gridbox layout., so elements can be spanning rows and columns without leaving a gap.

here is an example:

```css
.grid {
/* give some space gutters */
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding:1em;
  gap: 1em;
 /* build a grid */
  display: grid; 
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;/* fill any holes that could show up */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr)); /* auto calculate size of the grid */
  grid-auto-rows: 75px; /* give an height row for the demo */
  max-width: 80%;/* whatever */
  border: solid;/* see my boundaries */
}

.card {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.bigger {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-row: 1/ span 2;/* keep me on first row and lay over 2 rows */
  grid-column-end: -1; /* keep me on the last column no matter how many */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="bigger">I can be anywhere in the flow but I'll show on top end</div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>  
</div>
```

`row dense` , `auto-fill` &  `grid-column-end` are the rules/value that are usefull here to use :) among these see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I knew it could be done with grid but have wrongly assumed there's a way to achieve it with flexbox as well, thinking I simply wasn't skilled enough to execute it. Lesson learned :)

Comment: @DevToBe glad 4 you,  that is the main purpose of SO , helping ;)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using grid-layout without javascript, here's an example:

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px 300px;
  display: grid;
  /* auto calculate columns, minimun cell width is 140px */  
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(140px, 1fr));
  
  /* height of each cell */
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  gap: 20px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 490px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 22, 117);
}

.card {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.widget {
  background-color: rgb(134, 204, 245);
  /* widget, span for 2 rows */
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
  
  /* set the widget to the right most column */
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="widget"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>

<!-- Original jsx
<div className='container'>
  <div className='widget'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
  <div className='card'></div>
</div>
-->
```

As @ralph.m mentioned. You can always set `.widget` on the right most column by setting `grid-column-end: -1;` to your `.widget`

Comment: Thank you! Would the widget tag still have to be placed in the correct spot in HTML conditionally using JS, or is there a CSS solution for it as well? Also is there a way this can be done with flexbox, or is grid the only straightforward solution here?

Comment: Just add `grid-column-end: -1` at the end of the CSS styles to place the widget on the other side.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, means a lot :) `grid-column-end: -1;` this is also super useful to know for future reference as it'll save me from writing media queries :D